# MySQL: Get total number of customers within 5 miles of each unique location

Tags: mysql

I have this task where I need to find the total number of customers that are within 5 miles of each one of our locations listed in our database, and I'm not quite sure how to do that.  I'm kind of a noob when it comes to SQL queries and this one is a little out of my knowledge zone.  I have a query right now that will list all of the customers within 5 miles of just one location, but I want to get a report of them all.  I need the query to display something like this:

```
---------------------------
| Store    | Customers    |
| Store1   | 50           |
| Store2   | 300          |
| Store3   | 210          |
.          .              . 
.          .              .
---------------------------
```

The shortened schema for my stores table is like so:

This table consists of 200 entries

```
-------------------------------------------
| ID     | Lat          | Lng            |
| Store1 |43.7011526000 | -98.0822506000 |
| Store2 |42.7011526000 | -95.0822506000 |
.        .              .                .
.        .              .                .
-------------------------------------------
```

The shortened schema for my customers table is like so:

This table consists of 16K+ entries and growing

```
----------------------------------------------
| ID        | Lat          | Lng            |
| customer1 |40.7011526000 | -93.0822506000 |
| customer2 |41.7011526000 | -96.0822506000 |
.           .              .                .
.           .              .                .
----------------------------------------------
```

This is my query I currently have for getting the total number of customers within 5 miles of one of our stores:

```
select ID, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(43.7011526000) ) * cos( radians( Lat ) ) 
* cos( radians( Lng ) - radians(-98.0822506000) ) + sin( radians(43.7011526000) ) * sin(radians(Lat)) ) ) AS distance from customers having distance <= 5 order by distance;
```

I just hard coded in the latitude and longitude for the stores for right now, but I will want this to change per store.  If anyone knows how or if this can be done it would be very appreciated, TIA!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query - although I don't really understand which part of this you're struggling with.

Comment: @Strawberry I can't figure out how to query all stores instead of just one at a time.

Comment: It wasn't very hard, was it. Now go make a function out of that distance formula!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join the two tables and count the number within 5:

```
select stores.name as Store,
    sum( ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(stores.Lat) ) * cos( radians(customers.Lat) ) * cos( radians(stores.Lng) - radians(customers.Lng) ) + sin( radians(stores.Lat) ) * sin(radians(Lat)) ) ) <= 5 ) as Customers
from stores
cross join customers
group by stores.ID,stores.name
```

or use the distance constraint as your join condition:

```
select stores.name as Store,
    count(customers.ID) as Customers
from stores
left join customers
    on ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(stores.Lat) ) * cos( radians(customers.Lat) ) * cos( radians(stores.Lng) - radians(customers.Lng) ) + sin( radians(stores.Lat) ) * sin(radians(Lat)) ) ) <= 5
group by stores.ID,stores.name
```

Use `inner join` instead of `left join` if you want to skip stores with no nearby customers.